# Javacc common prefix error

Tags: javacc

New to JavaCC, don't know what is going on.
I have below grammar in JavaCC

```
<START_EXPR>
            (operator = <AND> | operator = <OR> | operator = <NOT>)
            (CondPassOperator(passingCondition) | VariableComparepassingCondition))+
<END_EXPR> 

<START_EXPR     : "(">
    |
<END_EXPR       : ")">
```

When I am compiling it getting below WARNING,

```
[javacc]          line 699, column 10 and line 699, column 58 respectively.
[javacc]          A common prefix is: "("
[javacc]          Consider using a lookahead of 2 for earlier expansion.
```

Any idea why I am getting this warning? This warning making my TeamCity build fail.

Comment: It would help if you posted the exact text of the entire production at line 699.  Also let us know which line is 699.

Comment: Also post the full text of the warning.  It looks like the first line is missing.